# Typesafe constraint on some keys of a Record<string,string> in Typescript

Tags: typescript, string-literals

Let's say I have a COUNTRIES const array somewhere :

```
const COUNTRIES = [
  "fr", "sp", "de", "uk"
] as const;

type CountryCode = typeof COUNTRIES[number];
```

And somewhere else, I have a big `Record<string,string>` map containing a bunch of translations for my app, something like :

```
const EN_TRANSLATIONS: Record<TranslationKeys, string> = {
  "hello-world": "Hello world !",
  "what-time": "What time is it ?",
  "countries.fr": "France",
  "countries.sp": "Spain",
  "countries.de": "Germany",
  "countries.uk": "United Kingdom"
}
```

Is it possible to define the `TranslationKeys` type above which would enforce following rules at compilation time :

- I should be able to define any string as the key without having to white list those in a union type (I don't want to maintain a dedicated union type for all of my keys)
- There should be some "special" keys following special conventions, and coupled to some type constraints. In my example, I would like that `countries.*` labels should represent the exhaustive list of COUNTRIES entries (matching the `CountryCode` union type) and, if this is not the case, I would like the compiler to complain that some country labels are missing (that way, whenever I add a new country code, I will not forget to provide its translation label)
- If possible, I would like to keep my `EN_TRANSLATIONS` type as is (I mean, only play with the `TranslationKeys` type) : typically, I know that one solution would be to introduce some (typed) variable and use spread operator like this :

```
const COUNTRY_EN_TRANSLATIONS: {[key in `countries.${CountryCode}`]: string} = {
  "countries.fr": "France",
  "countries.sp": "Spain",
  "countries.de": "Germany",
  "countries.uk": "United Kingdom"
}

const EN_TRANSLATIONS: Record<string, string> = {
  "hello-world": "Hello world !",
  "what-time": "What time is it ?",
  ...COUNTRY_EN_TRANSLATIONS
}
```

but I would like to avoid this (if possible).

I made some trials with the new `satisfies` keyword introduced in upcoming TS 4.9 version but it doesn't seem to play well either.

Any idea on how I could workaround this ?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: What's the point in doing all of that when the resulting type is still `Record<string, string>`?

Comment: The purpose is to have a compiler reminder telling me that I cannot create a new Country code without providing its corresponding translation.

I don't have strong requirements on the `Record<string,string>` type : if one found a good `TranslationKeys` type definition allowing me to enforce the country rule, then I'll be happy with a `Record<TranslationKeys, string>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close. But instead of simply a `Record`, you can do this by using a mapped type:

```
const COUNTRIES = [
  "fr", "sp", "de", "uk"
] as const;

type CountryCode = typeof COUNTRIES[number];
type MustHaveCountries = Record<string, string> & {
    [key in `countries.${CountryCode}`]: string;
}

const valid: MustHaveCountries = {
    "countries.ca": "foo",
    "countries.de": "foo",
    "countries.fr": "foo",
    "countries.sp": "foo",
    "countries.uk": "foo",
    'bar': "bar"
}


const invalid: MustHaveCountries = {
    "countries.ca": "foo",
    "countries.de": "foo",
    "countries.fr": "foo",
    "countries.sp": "foo",
    // "countries.uk": "foo", ERROR: Property '"countries.uk"' is missing in type
    'bar': "bar"
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WKO6DW)

Comment: Wow, didn't thought it would be that simple ! Thanks Slava :)